# Adding pagination to custom post loop in page

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have created a custom page template (testimonials-page.php) and in that template I am
loading custom post type 'testimonials' using the following loop:

```
<?php query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_type' => 'testimonials',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'paged' => $paged
 )
 ); ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="quote">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array($image_width,$image_height)); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

How do I add pagination to that? I installed the WP Paging plugin, and while that plugin works
great when I call the pagination into category.php using:

```
<p><?php wp_paging(); ?></p>
```

Inserting the same thing into testimonial-page.php results in broken formatting and links that
404 on me.

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, never EVER use query_posts unless your intention is to modify the default Wordpress Loop.

Instead, switch to [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Here's something I wrote for a theme I did for a client using all built-in Wordpress functions. It's been working pretty well for me so far, so I'll integrate it into your code as best as I can:

```
global $paged;
$curpage = $paged ? $paged : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="quote">
<?php
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array($image_width,$image_height));
the_content();
?>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;
    echo '
    <div id="wp_pagination">
        <a class="first page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">&laquo;</a>
        <a class="previous page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage-1 > 0 ? $curpage-1 : 1)).'">&lsaquo;</a>';
        for($i=1;$i<=$query->max_num_pages;$i++)
            echo '<a class="'.($i == $curpage ? 'active ' : '').'page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a>';
        echo '
        <a class="next page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage+1 <= $query->max_num_pages ? $curpage+1 : $query->max_num_pages)).'">&rsaquo;</a>
        <a class="last page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($query->max_num_pages).'">&raquo;</a>
    </div>
    ';
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

### Jan 2018 Edit:

Also consider using [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), since it's also built into Wordpress, and has more robust options and capabilities.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Just out of curiosity, why the emphatic never ever on query_posts usage?

Comment: I've implemented it and while it does display the pagination links, the links still 404 on me.

Check it out at http://s13.mynewsitereview.com/testimonials/

Comment: Some useful information on [WP Query vs Query Posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). Basically, you're modifying the default loop with every query, rather than interacting with the query object itself.

Comment: Also, your links stopped working due to your rewrites (most likely in your .htaccess file). This link works: [http://s13.mynewsitereview.com/?post_type=testimonials&page=3](http://s13.mynewsitereview.com/?post_type=testimonials&page=3)

Comment: Make a backup of your .htaccess file, delete it from your web server, and then try setting Pretty Permalinks under Settings->Permalinks. Hopefully, that should clear everything up (provided you have the latest version of Wordpress)

Comment: If all else fails, you can always hardcore the URL into your Pagination Links.

Comment: Unfortunately with the access I have to the server, I can't access .htaccess (wow...lotsa accesses there)... I went to my PErmalinks settings - I have /%postname%/ as my setting.

Comment: This works like charm +1. I have one doubt. `$id` in `get_the_post_thumbnail()` how does it gets the current post id even though the variable `$id` was not assigned to `the_ID()`. Does wordpress sets post id by default for this `$id`. Thanks @maiorano84

Comment: @sun You know what? I never even noticed that mistake in my example. Updated to `$post->ID` to reference the global post object within the loop. `get_the_ID()` would also work in this case.

Comment: @maiorano84 thanks for the reply. i used this `$id` with this inside the loop as `wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($id));` this works fine with and without $id too.Even though the $id is null. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @sun When using `get_the_post_thumbnail`, the first parameter is actually optional and will default to the current ID in the loop when a null value is given.

Comment: So the current post ID will be there in the loop even if we didn't specify. Also i notice when i use `the_ID()` alone in the `get_post_thumbnail_id(the_ID())` it is echoing the id in the front end i believe the `the_ID()` function return value is printable that is why am seeing that in front end.So i simply left the field now with `get_post_thumbnail_id(the_ID($i))` itself may be as you pointed out the reason in the above comment, that is the reason you didn't get any error in your try. @maiorano84

Comment: @sun Rule of thumb: `the_*()` are print functions. `get_the_*()` are return functions. Use `get_the_ID()` instead.

Comment: So i guess i am right. Thanks for the info. Once again good code for pagination. i haven't found like this in web as of now. I went to your site, in which any key typing code is creating right.if you can show some funny output after the end of code that would be catchy. If you have time and interested in that try that stuff. Cheers @maiorano84

Comment: How do you handle global $paged if this template is used as a static front page? Because [quote] When paging a static page, WordPress use the page variable, not the paged query variable. [/quote]
Having some issues with global $paged and a static front page

Comment: @alex - That's an excellent question. The [Wordpress Codex on Pagination within a Static Front Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page) has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for custom loop with pagination:

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    //'category_name' => 'custom-cat',
    'order' => 'DESC', // 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'date' // modified | title | name | ID | rand
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <?php
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $custom_query;
        ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
            <div class="prev-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query 
else:
    echo '<p>'.__('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.').'</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Source:

- [WordPress custom loop with pagination](http://web-profile.com.ua/wordpress/themes/wordpress-custom-loop/)