# Custom query pagination problem with php parameter as arg

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination, customization

I have create a loop with a custom query. This query contains a php parameters that i m getting from url with GET method. This the code at my loop page:

```
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    echo '<h1 class="childcatdes">'. $cat->name . '</h1>';
    echo '<p class="childcatdescr">'. $cat->description . '<br><br></p>';
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

    $posts_per_page = 12;
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


    $product_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'page' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field'    => 'name',
              'terms'    => $cat->name,
            ),
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'manufacturers',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $_GET['filter_manufacturers'],
              'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );

    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $product_args );

    if($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<ul';
        while ($custom_query->have_posts() )  : $custom_query->the_post(); 
            echo '<li>';
                $link = get_the_permalink();

                echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';

            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;


        echo '</ul>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'No post found.';
    }
    ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar( $custom_query); ?>
    </nav>
```

And i use this code to my functions.php file for the function pagination_bar

```
function pagination_bar( $custom_query) {
    $total_pages = $custom_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link(1)) . '%_%',
           'current' => $current_page,
           'format' => 'page/%#%/',
           'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages,
           'add_args' => array(
               'filter_manufacturers' => $_GET['filter_manufacturers'],
           )
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the pagination (even if it counts the posts correct at first page) is not working correct. I 'm getting 404 error at second page.

Comment: try not passing the page argument. just use paged.

Comment: Unfortunately problem is still there

Comment: try  echo pagination_bar( $custom_query );  instead of just pagination_bar($custom_query); and modify pagination bar function to return pagination links instead of echoing.

Comment: You should also after the pagination on loop page call wp_reset_postdata(); See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638909/adding-pagination-to-custom-post-loop-in-page for example

Comment: Thank you for your efford but nothing changed

Comment: Hmm. Is there errors getting triggered. Can you share the php error log.

Comment: There are no php errors, debug.log is empty